# Train and test with different datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-science, training-data

if i have 3 fake news datasets and i want to know which one is best to train a model, can i do this?
Train with A, test with B and C
train with B, test with A and C
train with C, test with A and B

I have created the fake news dataset A and would like to compare it with existing datasets B, C and D to see which one is better for training fake news binary detection and classification models. For this, I would like to know if it is okay to consider training a model with a set and evaluate that model with the remaining data sets, that is.

play with A, test with B, C and D

train with B, test with A, D and C

train with C, test with A, B and D

train with D, test with A, B and C